# show only duplicate values from array without builtin function PHP

Tags: php

For example:

```
$arr = array(3,5,2,5,3,9);
```

I want to show only common elements i.e 3,5 as output.

Comment: Why don't yu wanna use built-in functions?

Comment: it was asked in interview so dude.

Comment: You should show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my attempt:

```
<?php

  $arr = array(3,5,2,5,3,9);
  $temp_array = array();

  foreach($arr as $val)
  {
     if(isset($temp_array[$val]))
     {
       $temp_array[$val] = $val;
    }else{
     $temp_array[$val] = 0;
   }
 }

 foreach($temp_array as $val2)
 {
    if($val2 > 0)
    {
      echo $val2 . ', ';
    }
 }
```

?>

-- 
Output --

3, 5,

Comment: hey thanks @Phorce superb. can you please provide description of above code with comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$arr = array(3,5,2,5,3,9);
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
  //remove the item from the array in order 
  //to prevent printing duplicates twice
  unset($arr[$key]); 
  //now if another copy of this key still exists in the array 
  //print it since it's a dup
  if (in_array($val,$arr)){
    echo $val . " ";
  }
}
```

**Output:**
3 5

**Addition:**
I guess that the reason you were asked to implement it yourself (without using built-in functions) was to avoid answers like:

```
$unique = array_unique($arr); 
$dupes = array_diff_key( $arr, $unique );
```

Comment: He was asking question for interview. It could help him if you can explain the code. Please write few line. Your code is correct so I up voted it.

Comment: @user1182350 so is `echo` and `foreach`... See my "addition" above

Comment: I meant without using array function but foreach was allowed. Can you help me out

Comment: You can implement the same logic by concatenating the values into a string and do the same operations on a string (using `strpos`, `substr` etc).

Answer (score -3):

```
$arrnew = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
{
    for($j=$i+1;$j<count($arr);$j++)
    {
      if($arr[$i]==$arr[$j])
        {
          $arrnew[]=$arr[$j];
         } 
    }
}
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.